# Django, how to write SQL or ORM to sum something?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I want to count something like this:

input list:

- AAA female 1
- AAA female 2
- BBB male   2
- BBB male   1
- AAA male   1

output list:

- AAA male   1
- AAA female 3
- BBB male   3

Sorry, my english is not good, thanks for everyone who help me.

Comment: I believe you are looking for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: What are the fields / model that you need to sum?

Comment: My model fields is 'name', 'gender', 'count'. I want to combine data with same 'name' and 'gender', then sum them count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know your exact model struture, but the queries you need to run should be something like the following:

Assuming your model name is "YourModel", field containing "AAA" or "BBB" is "field_1", field containing "male" of "female" is "field_2", and the field containing numeric value is "field_3"

```
from django.db.models import Sum
YourModel.objects.filter(field_1='AAA', field_2='male').aggregate(sum=Sum('field_3')).get('sum')  # AAA male 1
YourModel.objects.filter(field_1='AAA', field_2='female').aggregate(sum=Sum('field_3')).get('sum')  # AAA female 3
YourModel.objects.filter(field_1='BBB', field_2='male').aggregate(sum=Sum('field_3')).get('sum')  # BBB male 3
```

I saw from your comment on the question that you want to group on name and gender, then sum their counts. You can do that with annotations as follows:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
YourModel.objects.values('name', 'gender').annotate(sum=Sum('count'))
```

Here you group by name and gender with the part **values('name', 'gender')** and annotate each name - gender pair row with the sum of counts.

Comment: Thanks, but i have a question. One aggregate only can generate one row data, Is there something can generate a list(all data)?

Comment: @Tony.Luo I think what you're looking for is annotations, with those, you can add computed values to each row of the result. You can read about them here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: @Tony.Luo I've updated the answer to add such a query

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can do this with simple aggregation. Assuming a table structure like `mytable(name, cnt)`, you would do:

```
select name, sum(cnt) sum_cnt
from mytable
group by name
```